# Using MS access Database as data source with DataGridView Cannot Seem to Update or Refresh DataGridView using conventional methods

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datasource, ms-access-2010

I have searched thoroughly for an answer to my question concerning a direct way to update a dataviewgrid with the call of a subroutine. but i had to luck, so im going to post the question here, with a little bit of background code and detail to help further your understanding on whats going on.

So i have 2 forms currently one being frmMain, this form contains three buttons 
btnAddItem - brings up frmAdd
btnSearch - no code yet
BtnPrint - no code yet

frm main also has a dataviewgrid - currently named dvgPEBGrid
i have this bound to a access database with the datasource named PEBTableBindingSource

now on to frmAdd
i have some fields that eventually get updated to the database
i successfully do this but after the form closes i cannot get the data grid to update 
i have tried a lot of things and what usually happens is my data grid just clears all data and i can not get the grid to return data until i close program and reset. any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What did you try? And how does frmAdd work? Does it add to the datagrid or directly to the database through sql?

Comment: it adds to the database through sql, also i have tried to clear the datagrid of bindings and rebind and the grid would just loose all data all together and wouldnt be reloaded.